# bad parallel-processing gain on some linux machines, good on others

Tags: parallel-processing

I'm measuring the run time for a complex signal-processing algorithm written in C on several different computers, all running linux. The code is partially parallelized by some of my own methods using the pthreads library, and by the parallel processing afforded by the FFTW package. Three of the four computers show expected decreases in execution time as the parallelism factor P increases from 1 to the number of physical cores on the machine. The problem is that one of the machines shows the opposite behavior: Going from P=1 to P=2 yields an increase in execution time.

The code is identical on the four machines, but the hardware and the OSs are not. Hyperthreading is on. All have large RAMs.

toren: Ubuntu 18.04.5, 4.15.0-122-generic, 4 physical cores, Xeon(R) CPU E3-1535M v5 @ 2.90GHz, gcc version 7.5

```
cmspooner@toren.mry.nwra.com>./ssca2_parallelism 
P = 1   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.025756e+01
P = 2   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 7.500780e+00
P = 4   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 6.246292e+00
P = 8   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 5.483851e+00
P = 16   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 7.457973e+00
P = 32   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 8.497999e+00
P = 64   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.035557e+01
```

twelve: Fedora Core 31, 5.8.15-101.fc31.x86_64, 12 physical cores, Xeon(R) CPU X5650 @ 2.67GHz, gcc version 9.3

```
cmspooner@twelve.mry.nwra.com>./ssca2_parallelism 
P = 1   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.833605e+01
P = 2   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.171951e+01
P = 4   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 8.526402e+00
P = 8   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 7.255262e+00
P = 16   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.268390e+01
P = 32   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.188247e+01
P = 64   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.417718e+01
```

flash: Fedora Core 31, 5.8.15-101.fc31.x86_64, 28 physical cores, Xeon(R) CPU E5-2697 v3 @
2.60GHz, gcc version 9.3

```
cmspooner@flash.mry.nwra.com>./ssca2_parallelism 
P = 1   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.462457e+01
P = 2   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.066421e+01
P = 4   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 8.244503e+00
P = 8   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 7.694590e+00
P = 16   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.030944e+01
P = 32   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.079129e+01
P = 64   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.413906e+01
```

barra: Ubuntu 18.04.4, 5.4.0-52-generic #57~18.04.1-Ubuntu, 8 physical cores, Xeon(R) W-3225 CPU @ 3.70GHz, gcc version 7.5

```
cmspooner@barra.mry.nwra.com>./ssca2_parallelism 
P = 1   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 8.891541e+00
P = 2   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.006297e+01
P = 4   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 8.619259e+00
P = 8   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 7.233214e+00
P = 16   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 7.765741e+00
P = 32   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 8.301655e+00
P = 64   ssca2: elapsed PROGRAM TIME 1.114389e+01
```

I've tried reverting barra's kernel to 4.15, but the result is similar.

The code is identical on each, I use gcc to compile on each, with the same Makefile (compiler switches).

Any ideas about why barra does not behave like the others?

Thanks,

C

Comment: What does the clock speed of the CPU on the last machine do when changing from 1 thread to 2? Perhaps the CPU can boost more with only 1 core running... otherwise does the CPU need thermal pasted changing? Does the CPU fan work? Could 1 core working not hit a thermal limit but more results in thermal throttling...

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks. I'll check it out. I assume the fan is working; I can't go into the office much due to the pandemic. I don't know what "thermal pasted changing" means. The computer is about six months old.

Comment: If the machine were old and the thermal paste between the CPU and heatsink were dry and cracked then the heatsink might not be making good contact and meaning that the CPU would thermally throttle a lot faster. Hence the paste would need to be replaced with new to make good contact.

Comment: @Mokubai Thanks. It is a new machine.

Comment: Changing the CPU governor settings from "powersave" to "performance" in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor did the trick.

Comment: The people in the office are probably wondering why the machine is five times noisier now with the fans going like jet engines. ;) Glad you found a fix.

Comment: @Mokubai Ha! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the CPU governor settings from "powersave" to "performance" in /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu*/cpufreq/scaling_governor did the trick.